# How to connect mongoDB with python?

Tags: python, mongodb

*I'm calling function with argument value database name. When I print argument other function it's working properly but when i'm connecting this argument value with database it's not giving any output*

**My code is Here.**

```
def myFunction(mydb):
    from pymongo import MongoClient
    print(mydb)
    client = MongoClient('localhost:27017')
    db = client.mydb
    data = db.collection.find().count()
    return data

mydb = 'my_databaseName'
myFunction(mydb);
```

*when I work with the above code it's returning:*

```
Oputput:0
```

*But when I'm working with this code it's working properly*

```
 def myFunction(mydb):
        from pymongo import MongoClient
        print(mydb)
        client = MongoClient('localhost:27017')
        db = client.my_databaseName #its static database name
        data = db.collection.find().count()
        return data
```

*So how can I solve this problem?*

Comment: yes, collection is existing in my database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to fetch the database directly, as its passed into your method:

```
from pymongo import MongoClient
client = MongoClient('localhost:27017')

def my_function(mydb):
    db = client.get_database(mydb)
    return db.collection.find().count()

print(my_function('my_database'))
```

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/mak705/Python_Mongo_Basics/blob/master/Python_Mongo_Basics.ipynb

```
import pymongo
myclient = pymongo.MongoClient("mongodb://localhost:27017/")
mydb = myclient["mydatabase"]

dblist = myclient.list_database_names()
if "mydatabase" in dblist:
  print("The database exists.")

#Create a collection called "customers":
mycol = mydb["customers"]
print(mydb.list_collection_names())
```