# How to connect mongodb to python?

Tags: python, mongodb

I am using python flask framework to develop Apis. I am planning to use mongodb as backend database. How can I connect mongodb database to python? Is there any in built in library?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to connect mongoDB with python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35152811/how-to-connect-mongodb-with-python)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You  can use Pymongo Library for the purpose.

```
from pymongo import MongoClient
client = MongoClient('MongoDB URL’)
```

For more info refer below link,

https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/getting-started-with-python-and-mongodb

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-python-driver

Yeah, there is.

Also documentation is here:
https://pymongo.readthedocs.io/en/stable/